# Standard distribution

Tags: distributions

i am working on a problem, it is in German i do my best to translate it. I have problems with the word „Standardverteilung“ which translated literally would mean standard distribution. I tried to ask on a German stat board but did not get an answer...i hope somebody can figure out what is meant

Problem

We have to universities and the age distribution of each of the university

[image]

I am asked to calculate the „standard distribution“ of university B.

I have never heard the term „Standardverteilung“ and no luck with google either.
Do they mean the standard normal...but how would i get a standard normal of the distribution of the distribution of University B. By standardizing like (x-E(X))/sd

Comment: I believe _Standardabweichung_ is _standard deviation._ You are probably being asked to "standardize" each of the two distributions. Standardizing $X_i$ would mean to transform as $Z_1 = \frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma}$ or $Z_i = \frac{X_i - \bar X}{S},$ if $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown and estimated by the sample mean and standard deviation. No reference to the standard normal distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ seems to be made or seems to be appropriate here.

Comment: Nowhere does it mention 'Standardabweichung' though, it only says 'Standardverteilung', which likely referes to 'Standard [Normal-] Verteilung', which would translate to [Standard Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution), which is $Norm(0,1)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, @BruceET's interpretation makes statistical sense whereas attempting to represent these histograms with Normal distributions does not.  (Such problems don't seem to prevent instructors and textbooks from asking students to do useless or meaningless things, unfortunately.)

Comment: Thanks, ok i will do both, maybe it is just some type of mistake and should say standard deviation.....who knows...i just thought i missed a concept i don’t even know about.....

Comment: @whuber Yes I agree in that it would make more sense, but from the wording it could mean both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this likely refers to the standard normal distribution and you can indeed scale an arbitrary normal distribution to a standard normal distribution (mean = 0, sd = 1) as you described.

Comment: How would i write it correct? $(X-E(X))/sd ~N(0,1)

Comment: Yes, this seems right to me. @Lillys